# ExtJS: Unable to logout using rails as backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, devise, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have an ExtJS6 app as frontend and rails at backend. Using devise for authentication. `sessions#destroy` looks like

```
    def destroy
      cookies.delete :auth_token
      reset_session
      sign_out(:user)
      render json: { success: true, message: 'Successfully logged out' }
    end
```

it does logs user out (seemingly) but refreshing page logs previous user in

It seems like cookies are not getting reset

Comment: As a minor point - it's a bad security practice to rely on deleting the cookie to sign people out. A bad agent could refuse to delete a cookie on the client side. Instead, on the server side, you should be ensuring that the cookie is no longer accepted as an authentication token. This would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two issues:

1. https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/486
2. https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/375

They explain why deleting your session may not be persisting. You'll need to override your sessions controller. Full explanation there.

Comment: that's not the only possible problem. That's just the context they were experiencing the problem in. the `CSRF token` is a possible problem.